# Should you make a variable static to protect it from getting deleted over the long term?

Tags: java, android

Say your android app has an accessibility service with a variable that it should always be able to use. The variable in this case is called `sharedPreferences`. It gets assigned a value only once in its lifetime in the `onServiceConnected()`. Will this non-static variable retain its value after 5 months of not being touched or will it somehow get emptied? Am I misunderstanding what static and non-static is?

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();

        AccessibilityServiceInfo configuration = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        configuration.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
        configuration.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        setServiceInfo(configuration);

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
            if (some kind of rare event) {
                String string = sharedPreferences.getString("key", "default");
                ...
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static just means the variable is not tied to a specific instance of the class - if your service/app/task is stopped the static variable will still be garbage collected. If you make a non-static class member variable and set it in `onServiceConnected` you can be guaranteed that it will be valid for any method called in that class after `onServiceConnected`.

Even if the service is stopped and restarted, once it calls `onServiceConnected` on the new instance the class variable will be valid again.